# Reducing installation of libraries

Tags: c++

I have a C++ project that have like 15+ external libraries installed with a package mananger. The problem is with the package change, the newest versions of some library break things (like libblob). I wanted to know if it exists a way to not relaying on some package manager for installing our library and to make sure we always have the version we want.

Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Please clarify the OS and the package manager in question.

Comment: We use two linux distro : Ubuntu and ArchLinux.
Then,
We use two package manager : APT and pacman.

Even if we use one package manager, the problem will still be there because of the upgrade.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you don't want to use a package manager, then don't use a package manager.
apt is a great tool and is there to help, but you aren't required to use it.
On Ubuntu, you might want to just use dpkg instead of apt and so that none
of the dependencies will be automatically updated and avoid upgrading the
libraries that are causing problems.  Or, just install everything directly
from source.  If you go that route, install to  /usr/local or some
non-standard location.  (ie, do NOT configure --prefix=/usr &&
make && make install.  Use the default /usr/local or $HOME for prefix.)

Note that doing this is a heinous kludge, and you have bigger problems.  If you 
are relying on libraries that are unstable, then you probably ought to consider
removing your dependency on those libraries.  Also, mixing usage of dpkg with
apt will cause maintenance headaches.  If you do that, only do it on your
developmental boxes (eg, not on production servers.)  Your primary concern
should be to get your package working correctly with the package management
system, and one part of this may involve fixing the packaging of all the
libraries you depend on.

Comment: That's how you shoot yourself in the foot when it comes to distributing your software.

Comment: We don't distribute the software :). We always using it from the source. 

I'm not sure to understand why it's shooting in the foot. When you distribute your software you want your application to use the version of library you used during the development... no?

Comment: If your are going to use this application internally then it's ok but users won't really like it if you say to them that they need to compile 15 libraries before they can use your software.

Comment: @plcstpierre: no, you do not want your distributed app to use the same version of the library used during development.  You want your app to use the newest compatible version, so that bugs fixed in the library are fixed in your app.

Answer (score 4):

One way to solve that problem is to staticaly link your libraries but that will increase your application size.